# jQuery: Change div text on click, will not work more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```js
    var woocommerce_price_displayed = $('.product_intial_price').find('.woocommerce-Price-amount').text();

        $(".yearly-package").click(function () {
        var yearprice = $('#year_price').text();
    $('.electro-price').find('.woocommerce-Price-amount').text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace(woocommerce_price_displayed, yearprice); 
});
    })

    $(".halfyear-package").click(function () {
       var halfyearprice = $('#halfyear_price').text();
$('.electro-price').find('.woocommerce-Price-amount').text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace(woocommerce_price_displayed, halfyearprice); 
});
    })

    $(".single-package").click(function () {
      var oneprice = $('#one_price').text();
$('.electro-price').find('.woocommerce-Price-amount').text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace(woocommerce_price_displayed, oneprice); 
});
    })
```

When div is clicked, the price will change. However, if I click again on a different button - the price will not change again.

What's wrong? Why will it work on the first click only?

This is basically the html for each pack:

```
<div class="ps-package single-package first-pack" data-val="1">
<div class="ps-name">Single Package</div>
<div id="one_price" class="ps-price">$99</div>

</div>

<span class="electro-price"><ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>99.00</span></ins> <del><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>150.00</span></del></span>
```

When I add `var woocommerce_price_displayed = oneprice;` for each of the function like this:

```
    $(".halfyear-package").click(function () {
       var halfyearprice = $('#halfyear_price').text();
$('.electro-price').find('.woocommerce-Price-amount').text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace(woocommerce_price_displayed, halfyearprice); 
    woocommerce_price_displayed = halfyearprice;
});
```

It will not work at all, not even once! Why?

Comment: Your `var woocommerce_price_displayed` should be a global variable, place it outside the methods, than inside the functions do not use `var` no more. Since you use `var` inside the methods - it means you re-declare variable and its scope is not global any more, it becames new variable. Also things like `var yearprice = $('#year_price').text();` on each click are redundant, move them out of methods.

Comment: @skobaljic - Thanks for your help. But how can I still update the `woocommerce_price_displayed` variable after each "click"?